# How to Increase performance of API call

Tags: api, c#-4.0

I am using 5 Hotels APIs and trying to combine and pick min price hotel with unique hotels from all APIs. I am following these STEPS

1. Call All 5 APIsand wait for response.
2. get all static data from database or if avail my server caching(all 5 APIs like hotels name, images, desc, etc)
3. Combine into one custom class
4. get GIATA map codes from caching or database.
5. Apply GIATA into API result and group all hotels with unique GIATA id.
6. Pick min price .
7. Bind UI and show to customer.

   ```
       string sessionid = sqf;
           DS.Models.BL.Common.HotelSearchDetails details = new DS.Models.BL.Common.HotelSearchDetails();
           details = (.Models.BL.Common.HotelSearchDetails)Session["Details_" + sessionid];
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> DOTWhdlist = new List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> GTAhdlist = new List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> HPhdlist = new List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> HBhdlist = new List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> TSGhdlist = new List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>();
           //GTA City Cache
           DS.Models.BL.GTA_Model.Methods.HotelInfo hinfo = new Models.BL.GTA_Model.Methods.HotelInfo();
           List<GTA.API.HotelSearch.GTAHotels> hlist = new List<GTA.API.HotelSearch.GTAHotels>();
           hlist = hinfo.GethotellistCityWise(details.GTACityCode);
           //

           /*************************************************
            * DOTW cache
            * 
            *************************************************/
           DS.BL.DOTW.Method.HotelInfo objhoteldetails = new DS.BL.DOTW.Method.HotelInfo();
           Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = objhoteldetails.Gethotelratings();
           List<DOTW.Method.searchhotels.DotwHotels> objhotellist = new List<DOTW.Method.searchhotels.DotwHotels>();
           objhotellist = objhoteldetails.GethotellistCityWise(details.DOTWCityCode);
           //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


           //------Hotel pro cache city

           DS.BL.HotelsPro.Method.GetHotelDetails objhoteldetails_hp = new BL.HotelsPro.Method.GetHotelDetails();
           List<HotelsPro.Method.Avail.HotelsProHotels> objhotellist_hp = new List<HotelsPro.Method.Avail.HotelsProHotels>();
           objhotellist_hp = objhoteldetails_hp.GethotellistCityWise(details.HotelsProCityCode);

           /***************************************************
            * Hotelbeds city cache
            * 
            */
           DS.Models.BL.HotelBeds.Methods.HotelInfoController objhotelbeds = new DS.Models.BL.HotelBeds.Methods.HotelInfoController();
           List<HotelBeds.Method.SearchHotel.HotelBedsHotels> HBhotellist = new List<HotelBeds.Method.SearchHotel.HotelBedsHotels>();
           HBhotellist = objhotelbeds.GethotellistCityWise(details.HBCityCode);
           /**************************************************
            * 
            *  TSG city cache
            * 
            */
           DS.Models.BL.TSG.Methods.HotelInfo objtsg_hotel = new Models.BL.TSG.Methods.HotelInfo();
           List<TSG.API.HotelAvail.TSGHotels> TSGhlist = new List<TSG.API.HotelAvail.TSGHotels>();
           TSGhlist = objtsg_hotel.GethotellistCityWise(details.City);

           //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           var dotw = Task<List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(() => Dotw(sqf, details, dictionary, objhotellist));
           var gta = Task<List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GTA(sqf, details, hlist));
           var hotelpro = Task<List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(() => Hp(sqf, details, objhotellist_hp));
           var hotelbeds = Task<List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(() => HB(sqf, details, HBhotellist));
           var tsg = Task<List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(() => TSG(sqf, details, TSGhlist));

           DOTWhdlist = dotw.Result;
           TSGhdlist = tsg.Result;
           GTAhdlist = gta.Result;
           HPhdlist = hotelpro.Result;
           HBhdlist = hotelbeds.Result;
           ViewBag.sessionId = sessionid;
           DOTWhdlist.AddRange(GTAhdlist);
           DOTWhdlist.AddRange(HPhdlist);
           DOTWhdlist.AddRange(HBhdlist);
           DOTWhdlist.AddRange(TSGhdlist);
           string[] c = details.CityName.Split(',');
           string cityname = c[0];
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> filterdata = GiataApply(DOTWhdlist, cityname, details.GiataCityid);
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> tsgdata = filterdata.Where(x => x.giataref == "exclusivelyhotels").ToList();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> gtadata = filterdata.Where(x => x.giataref == "gta").ToList();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> dotwdata = filterdata.Where(x => x.giataref == "DOTW").ToList();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> hpdata = filterdata.Where(x => x.giataref == "metglobal").ToList();
           List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> hbdata = filterdata.Where(x => x.giataref == "hotelbeds").ToList();

           allSup.dotw = dotwdata;
   ```

GIATA APPLY

```
List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> GiataApply(List<DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails> hlist, string city, int Cityid)
    {
        DS.Models.BL.Common.GIATA.giataCodes giataCodes = new Models.BL.Common.GIATA.giataCodes();
        List<GiataProperty> gcode = new List<GiataProperty>();
        gcode = giataCodes.GiataCodes(city, Cityid);
        var query = from h in hlist
                    join g in gcode on new { hotelcode = h.HotelId, supcode = h.giataref }
                    equals new { hotelcode = g.Hcode, supcode = g.ProviderCode }
                    select new DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails
                    {
                        HotelName = h.HotelName,
                        HCode = h.HCode,
                        HotelId = h.HotelId,
                        Address = h.Address,
                        image = h.image,
                        location = h.location,
                        Currency = h.Currency,
                        searchId = h.searchId,
                        Price = h.Price,
                        rating = h.rating,
                        hoteldescription = h.hoteldescription,
                        Latitude = h.Latitude,
                        Longitude = h.Longitude,
                        imagelist = h.imagelist,
                        Source = h.Source,
                        giataref = h.giataref,
                        HFullResponse = h.HFullResponse,
                        AvailableRoomList = h.AvailableRoomList,
                        HotelRooms = h.HotelRooms,
                        facilities = h.facilities,
                        faDetails = h.faDetails,
                        giata = g.giataId.Value,
                        hotelservices = h.hotelservices,
                        gtaIDref = h.gtaIDref
                    };



        var filter = from x in query
                     group x by x.giata into hotels
                     select new DS.BL.Common.HotelDetails
                     {
                         HotelName = hotels.FirstOrDefault().HotelName,
                         HCode = hotels.FirstOrDefault().HCode,
                         HotelId = hotels.FirstOrDefault().HotelId,
                         Address = hotels.FirstOrDefault().Address,
                         image = hotels.FirstOrDefault().image,
                         location = hotels.FirstOrDefault().location,
                         Currency = hotels.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                         searchId = hotels.FirstOrDefault().searchId,
                         imagelist = hotels.FirstOrDefault().imagelist,
                         Price = hotels.Min(p => p.Price),
                         rating = hotels.FirstOrDefault().rating,
                         hoteldescription = hotels.FirstOrDefault().hoteldescription,
                         Latitude = hotels.FirstOrDefault().Latitude,
                         Longitude = hotels.FirstOrDefault().Longitude,
                         Source = hotels.FirstOrDefault().Source,
                         giataref = hotels.FirstOrDefault().giataref,
                         HFullResponse = hotels.FirstOrDefault().HFullResponse,
                         AvailableRoomList = hotels.FirstOrDefault().AvailableRoomList,
                         HotelRooms = hotels.FirstOrDefault().HotelRooms,
                         facilities = hotels.FirstOrDefault().facilities,
                         faDetails = hotels.FirstOrDefault().faDetails,
                         giata = hotels.FirstOrDefault().giata,
                         hotelservices = hotels.FirstOrDefault().hotelservices,
                         gtaIDref = hotels.FirstOrDefault().gtaIDref
                     };

        return filter.ToList();
        //return query.ToList();
    }
```

No this process taking 30-45 sec . i want to reduce i dont know how i do but in API calling i need to reduce time and GIATA apply .

give me idea guys thanks

Comment: Why still im getting negative marking for this question due to don't understand my question. amazing guys.

Answer (score 1):

Find async version of your API calls and use them. That should solve your problem. If no async version is available then you will have to do it in your code of C#. I am not a C# expert so I cannot help you there.

Comment: if you see my code i am calling APIs in Task so this call parallel so there is no need to call async here

Comment: Profile your code. Is it API call taking time or SQL?